# Passing arguments to Faker for my method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, faker

I have a model called Booking, that should calculate the total from several numbers (amount, deposit, and fee are all added together). I'm having trouble getting these arguments to be seen in Faker.

```
it "should calculate the total" do 
  myvar = FactoryGirl.create(:booking, :amount => 900, :deposit => 20, :fee => 8)
  myvar.totalamount.should == 928
end
```

And here's my method:

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :to, :from, :amount, presence: true

  def totalamount(amount,deposit,fee)
    total = (amount + deposit + fee)
    return total 
  end 
end
```

The error message: "wrong number of arguments (0 for 3)"

However, when I do a `puts myvar.deposit`, it returns the value I gave it - 20. 
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is my Factory build for Booking:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :booking do |b|
    b.from { Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count=3) }
    b.to { Faker::Lorem.sentence(word_count=3) }
    b.amount { Faker::Number.digit }
  end
end
```

Comment: Omg someone pls help D:

Comment: Solved by removing the (amount,deposit,fee) after def totalamount.

Comment: hey, if you have a working solution - feel free to add it as an answer (rather than a comment). This marks your question as solved, so people don't think you still need help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :to, :from, :amount, presence: true

  def totalamount
    total = (amount + deposit + fee)
    return total 
  end 
end
```

Just had to remove the 3 required attributes after 'totalamount'.